# ASP.NET BoundField properties -- setting width

Tags: c#, asp.net

I asked a question yesterday ["Accessing the value of a passed in argument to click event c#"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111190/accessing-the-value-of-a-passed-in-argument-to-click-event-c-sharp) and provided some code.  As it turns out, I stumbled on a fact that one cannot reference the value of a hidden `boundfield`.  So, is there another way to "hide" the field from the user (because it's irrelevant to them) while maintaining access to it so I can use it in code behind?  Should I be using a different form element?

I tried to set `ItemStyle-Width="1%"` but it still shows up on the form.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Can you reference the question you asked or show some code?

Comment: The reference to the question yesterday is in today's question ... However, I seem to have found the answer by revising the search... see below...

Comment: If your are trying to reference these via some client-side code, then it's likely that the `Visible="false"` is causing your problem. This will cause your element to not be rendered in the DOM at all and thus inaccessible. If you want it to still be rendered, consider using CSS to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

The question "Hide BoundField's but still be able to get values with C#" provided the answer to my question...

The use of 'DataKeyNames' solved the problem.

```
DataKeyNames="projectLineageID, projectHasRelTypeID, relProjectID"
```

Then accessing them like this...

```
string relID = gvProjectLineage.DataKeys[grdrow.RowIndex].Values["projectLineageID"].ToString();
```

I love this site... Just have to learn how to do searches a bit better before posting questions.

Bob